# Offset.Clear crashes excel when try to run in change mode

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear a cell in worksheet change mode in VBA.

However, when I try to clear cell which is just a number Excel crashes and stops working.

[image]

I am trying to clear "5" when I deleted "asd" Cell.

```vb
If IsEmpty(Target.value) Then
    'Target.Offset(0, 3).Validation.Delete
    Target.Offset(0, 3).Clear
```

It gives me the error "Range of Object worksheet Failed"

Full Code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Range
    Set i = Range("A1:A1000")
    Dim b As Range
    Set b = Range("b1:b1000")
    Dim t As Range
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, i) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "-"
        Debug.Print "Start"
        Debug.Print "****************"
        
        Set t = Target
        mak1 t
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, b) Is Nothing Then
        Set t = Target
        mak2 t
        Range("D3").Clear
    End If
    
    If IsEmpty(Target.value) Then
        Debug.Print Target.Address.Offset(0, 3)
        
        'Target.Offset(0, 3).Validation.Delete
        Target.Offset(0, 3).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of Target.Address when it fails?  Are you disabling events so you don't end up in a loop with any changes applied by your event code?  Would help to show the rest of your code here.

Comment: I editted and add some picture.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code for us to guess what the problem is.

Comment: I edited again. This is the code already, in the background there is no relation between macros.

Comment: What are `mak1` and `mak2` ?

Comment: You should set  `Application.EnableEvents = False` in your change-routine when you plan to modify any data within that routine, else the Change-Event will be called recursively. Don't forget to set it to True at the end of the routine,  and use an error handler so that it is enabled in any case

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas it worked pretty well Could you share the answer?

Comment: @TimWilliams these are my macros which includes creating a dictionary from table, thanks for your help too.

Comment: I didn't provide an answer because this has already been asked too many times on SO. I only don't have the time to look for a good matching question to mark this as duplicate.